# ScheduledDisposable

Tags: idisposable, system.reactive, reactive-programming

What is a good case/example for using the **ScheduledDisposable** in Reactive **Rx**

I like the using the **CompositeDisposable** and **SerialDisposable**, but would you need the **ScheduledDisposable**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic of using the Rx disposables is that code that performs some sort of set up operation can return an `IDisposable` that anonymously contains the code that will do the associated clean up at a later stage. If this pattern is used consistently then you can compose together many disposables to perform a single clean up operation without any specific knowledge of what is being cleaned up.

The problem is that if that clean up code needs to run on a certain thread then you need some way for `Dispose` called on one thread to be marshalled to required thread - and that's where `ScheduledDisposable` comes in.

The primary example is the `SubscribeOn` extension method which uses `ScheduledDisposable` to ensure that the "unsubscribe" (i.e. the `Dispose`) is run on the same `IScheduler` that the `Subscribe` was run on.

This is important for the `FromEventPattern` extension method, for example, that attaches to and detaches from event handlers which must happen on the UI thread.

Here's an example of where you might use `ScheduledDisposable` directly:

```
var frm = new SomeForm();

frm.Text = "Operation Started.";

var sd = new ScheduledDisposable(
    new ControlScheduler(frm),
    Disposable.Create(() =>
        frm.Text = "Operation Completed."));

Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(() =>
{
    // Long-running task
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    sd.Dispose();
});
```

A little contrived, but it should show a reasonable example of how you'd use `ScheduledDisposable`.